# Prove that if $\gcd{f, P_A} = 1$ for some matrix $A$ and polynom $f$ then $f(A)$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $f \in F[x]$ and $A \in M_{n x n} (\mathbb F)$. Prove: If $\gcd\{f,P_A\} = 1 \rightarrow f(A)$ is an invertible matrix.

This is what I did so far:

> If the $\gcd\{f,P_A\} = 1$ then $f$ and $P_A$ have no common divisors, and do not have the same roots. From the Cayley-Hamilton rule we know that $P_A(A) = 0$. In addition, $\gcd\{f, m_A\}=1$ because $m_A$ and $P_A$ have the same roots. Now I said: $f(A) \neq 0$, because the ideal $ I= \{g(x) | g(A)=0\}$ is created by $m_A$ and since $\gcd\{f, m_A\} = 1$ then $f(A) \not \in I$ which means $f(A) \neq 0$. That means that the element $(xI - A)$ is not in $f$.

And right there is where I could not continue.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that LaTeX has a command \gcd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Bezout identity and since $\gcd(f,P_A)=1$ then there's $U,V\in\mathbb{F}[x]$ s.t.

$$Uf+VP_A=1$$
hence
$$U(A)f(A)+V(A)P_A(A)=U(A)f(A)=I$$
so $f(A) $ is invertible.

**Added** this is another proof  without use of Bezout identity

The matrix $f(A)$ is invertible if and only if $0$ isn't one of it's eigenvalues, moreover it's easy to see that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$ and since $\gcd(f,P_A)=1$ then $f$ and $P_A$ haven't a common root hence we can conclude.

Comment: We haven't learned and are not allowed to use the "Bezout identity"

Comment: @TheNotMe I added another proof.

Comment: Didn't understand the connection between $f(\lambda)$ being an eigenvalue of $f(A)$ and that the gcd is 1. at all.

Comment: @TheNotMe If $\lambda$ is a root of $P_A$ then it's not a root of $f$ and then the eigenvalues $f(\lambda)$ of $f(A)$ isn't $0$ so $f(A)$ is invertible.

Comment: The problem that is confusing me: let $\lambda$ be root of of $P_A$, then $\lambda$ is not a root of $f(A)$. But who said that $f(\lambda)$ can't be $0$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is root of $P_A$ then it isn't root of $f$ since $\gcd(P_A,f)=1$ and then $f(\lambda)\neq0$. Now remember as I said that $f(\lambda)\neq0$ is eigenvalue of $f(A)$ so $f(A)$ is invertible because all its eigenvalues are different of $0$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. I have another small question on the way if you can: If I proved that a matrix $A \in M_{nxn} (F)$ is not invertible (it has eigenvalue 0) and given $trace(A)=0$, is it diagonalizable?